# How to modify values inside a data file in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to allow the user to modify values from a data file. I'm using class members to hold the value as well as an array

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class student
{
 private:
    string stuID;
    string lastN;
    string firstN;
    float GPA;
    int numb_of_enrolled;
 public:
    void displayAll();
    void setAll(string StuID, string LastN, string FirstN, float gpa, int nof);
};

const int SIZE = 30;
int main()
{
    ifstream inFile;
    int option, count, scount = 0, cIndex;
    student stuFile[SIZE];
    string sID, sLN, sFN;
    float sgpa;
    int snof;
    char repeat = 'y';

    inFile.open("Students.dat", ios::in);

    cout << "MENU\n";
    cout << "3. Change an Existing Record's Fields\n";
    cout << "What would you like to do?: ";
    cin >> option;
    cin.ignore();

    switch(option) {
        case 3:
            inFile >> sID >> sLN >> sFN >> sgpa >> snof;

            cout << "There are 19 Students in this data file\n";
            cout << "Enter an Index from 0 - 19: ";
            cin >> cIndex;
            cin.ignore();

            stuFile[cIndex].setAll(sID, sLN, sFN, sgpa, snof);
            stuFile[cIndex].displayAll();
    }
}

void student::displayAll()
{
    cout << "Student ID: " << stuID << endl;
    cout << lastN << ", " << firstN << endl;
    cout << numb_of_enrolled << " Classes taken this Semester\n";
    cout << "Current GPA is: " << GPA << "\n\n";
}

void student::setAll(string StuID, string LastN, string FirstN, float gpa, int nof)
{
    stuID = StuID;
    lastN = LastN;
    firstN = FirstN;
    GPA = gpa;
    numb_of_enrolled = nof;
}
```

So the data file has 19 records inside of it. Case 3 works but not how it should. If I enter 3, it doesn't go to the third record inside of it but it stays at 0. Even if I use .eof(), it would still be stuck at element 0. How can I make it so that I'm able to get to the record I want?

Comment: can you put single line of data from the file, I will help you

Comment: AF101 Smith Zachery 3.5 3 @DickensAS

Comment: use my code, you need reach the line via a loop, or you need seek methods in fstream

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop for N lines for the cIndex, declare `int i` and do this code

```
case 3:
    cout << "There are 19 Students in this data file\n";
    cout << "Enter an Index from 0 - 19: ";
    cin >> cIndex;
    cin.ignore();
    for(i=0;i<cIndex;i++) {
       inFile >> sID >> sLN >> sFN >> sgpa >> snof;
    }

    stuFile[cIndex].setAll(sID, sLN, sFN, sgpa, snof);
    stuFile[cIndex].displayAll();

    inFile.clear();
    inFile.seekg(0);
```

Comment: It displays all 5, I only need it to display what is called. So if AF101 Smith Zachery 3.5 3 is in the element 4. I need it to skip 1 - 3 and only display 4.

Comment: as per the code, it will only read all the lines but only display 1 line, in my computer, may be you have more code without break statement inside the switch, only `stuFile[cIndex].displayAll()` will display the values, `inFile >> sID >> sLN >> sFN >> sgpa >> snof` will just read the values and keeps them in those variables, I tested this code in my local :)

Comment: Oh, I had the stuFile things inside the for loop, taking it out solved the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Now I'm running into a different problem. Since it's reading the values and keeping them in those variables. I have to reopen it as a ofstream so that I can modify the values within the datafile

Comment: no need to reopen use seek zero from my answer to rewind the file to begining, to display the values you can use local variables instead of SID, use a local SID1 and only for display, in C++ no need to declare all variable on top, you can declare variable locally

Comment: But I need to overwrite the things inside the file to modify it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210589/discussion-between-dickens-a-s-and-noodlez).